# Only affect elements in container

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a huge CSS/bootstrap file and it affects not just the elements. I want it to do that, but the css affects the whole page. I can't change every elements name to [name].slider. So is there an easy way to make it only affect elements inside a container?

```
<head>
<!--the stuff in here is also affected-->
</head>

<div>
<!--Stuff to get affected-->
</div>
```

Comment: add some code whatever you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, put an id or class on the target div, and add that id or class to the start of the css file. If you are using Less or Sass you can just nest the contents of the entire file inside a rule with the id or class.

```css
.my-styled-section h3 {
  color: green;
}

.my-styled-section {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <!--the stuff in here is no longer affected-->
  <h3>Test</h3>
  <p>Test</p>
</head>

<div class="my-styled-section">
  <!--Stuff to get affected-->
  <h3>Test</h3>
  <p>Test</p>
</div>
```